# How do I cause an MVC controller to redirect the user from an ajax call?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am sending an array as the "data" value (parameters) of an ajax call to an MVC controller. The controller should then redirect the user to a new page but it does not. Instead I can see in the Preview window that the View is being returned but through the ajax return. I am not sure if the way I am approaching this is correct because I seem to be having a hard time finding good examples to follow. I wanted to avoid an Html.ActionLink because I will have about 20 parameters to pass to the controller.

Here is the function that sends the array to the controller:

```
submit: function () {
        var data = {
            "ReqDepartment": (viewModel.reqDepartment === null) ? null : viewModel.reqDepartment,
            "EquipmentGroup": (viewModel.equipmentGroup === null) ? null : viewModel.equipmentGroup,
            "SiteCode": (viewModel.site === null) ? null : viewModel.site.SiteCode,
            }; //header
      $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/ArctecLogisticsWebApp/Requisitions/ReqsSummary/",
                data: data,
                traditional: true
       });
     }
```

Here is the controller, ReqSearchCriteria is a ViewModel :

```
public ViewResult ReqsSummary(ReqSearchCriteria criteria)
    {
return View("ReqsSummary", requisitionsRepository.GetReqsAdvancedSearch(criteria));
    }
```

The controller is returning the View in the ajax call.  Should I use a different approach to send an array to the controller?

Comment: If your action method is returning HTML, then you can simply use jQuery's `load()` method and replace the contents of the page with the returned HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ajax calls won't redirect by themselves.  what you need to do is return json from the controller to the view with the result of the action and if the action is successful then redirect

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/ArctecLogisticsWebApp/Requisitions/ReqsSummary/",
    data: data,
    traditional: true,
    success: function(result){
        if(result.Success){
            window.location = '@Url.Action('Action', 'Contorller')';
        }
    }
});
```

Edit:

The controller method you have will work.  It should be a different name from the form you are redirecting from to eliminate confusion.  Through data you can pass any information that you need.

```
data: { id: $('.id').val() },
```

something like this will pass whatever value is in the field with class id.  then on your controller create the model for the view and return view.  I use ajax calls everywhere,  they are incredibly useful.  Please let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: They redirect themselves if you return the right content type.

Comment: @Matt Bodily, The result of the action should be to redirect the user and include the data generated from a repository using the parameters passed in the ajax call. I'm starting to think an ajax call is not the best way to redirect a user. None of the answers make any sense to me so I must not be asking the question correctly.

Comment: see my edit above.  Please let me know if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 1):

You don't *have* to check for a result in your success/done handler and then do the redirect manually. You can actually return a JavascriptResult from your controller and it will redirect for you:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '/Home/DoStuff'
});

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DoStuff()
{
    return JavaScript(string.Format("window.location='{0}';", Url.Action("About")));
}
```

If you wanted to get fancy you could even create a new ActionResult type that took care of the formatting for you. Or you could detect if it is an AjaxRequest and determine if you should do a RedirectToAction or a JavaScript result.

Comment: @Dismissle, I don't really understand how your solution would work in my case. I will have about 20 parameters I will pass to the controller, the controller will then use those parameters to populate a different View and return the view to the user. I could make this work by using an ActionLink and concatenating all the parameters but I'm looking for a cleaner solution. Sorry if I am not making myself clear enough here.

Comment: So add parameters to the ajax call. You just asked how you could redirect from an AJAX call. I'm showing the relevant part of that. If you return a JavaScript result that does window.location = '...', it will redirect.